# Do all GCP workflow errors have a message field?

Tags: google-cloud-platform

I am looking into error handling and I see that these are the different error tags: https://cloud.google.com/workflows/docs/reference/syntax/error-types

I know in GCP, in general, when the workflow throws an error, the error is a map consisting of fields
I was wondering if there is a way to know for a each of the error tags, what the "error map" consists of. I can only find it for "HttpError" (for "HttpError": it has e.tags, e.code, e.body, e.message, e.headers). but I'm not able to find it for anything else. I see for some of them, they have "e.message", but I don't want to assume anything first because I haven't been able to find anything regarding this on GCP documentation online

Comment: Do you talk about Workflows errors, or errors that a Cloud Workflow step can receive? I assume it's the second case. If so, an HTTP error is a HTTP response with a HTTP code different from 2XX. So, if the API called with Workflow returns nothing except an error code, you won't have any message in the error handler.

Comment: No I mean GCP workflow errors, as shown in the link. There are multiple errors that can occur within a workflow